# GIT summary of changes since initialising repository

Tags: git

Just out of curiosity I want to see the total amounts of insertions, deletions and other modifications on my GIT repository since it was first created.

Similar to `git log --stat` but for all commits.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just find the SHA1 of the first commit in your repository.  One way to do that would be to run `git log --graph --pretty=oneline` -- the last line you see should be the first commit in the repository.  Take that SHA1 and run

```
git diff --stat <SHA1>..
```

also, possibly interesting, may be

```
git shortlog -s
```

You may also find [gitstat](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitstat/) interesting.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
git diff --stat ORIG_HEAD..HEAD
```

Comment: `ORIG_HEAD` isn't since the creation, it's just since the last thing that would've moved the head (e.g. a reset, rebase, or merge operation will set `ORIG_HEAD` before it begins).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Would you happen to know if there is a keyword that references the first commit? I feel like I'm running circles around the documentation trying to find a section that would tell me either way.