# git diff for a repo since origin

Tags: git

Is there a way to run a `git diff` on an entire project and get a text file output that represents all changes between origin and the present state of the project?

I know that there are similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604654/git-summary-of-changes-since-initialising-repository), but I'm looking not for a summary but the full, verbose output so that I can make sure that there isn't any sensitive data in the repo.

Comment: Your question is unclear

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you need one huge diff:

```
git diff origin/master
```

This shows the difference of the tip of the current branch against origin master.

But note that if the sensitive data were added in one commit and then removed in a subsequent one, they are still retrievable.

If you need that type of repository, it is much better to make sure the sensitive data are never published.  Let someone be responsible for the public one and let him review every individual commit before it gets there.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the question correctly, you went every commit as a patch?

```
git log -U --full-diff -p
```